# Mac can acceess internet but r and python3 can't

Tags: python, r, macos

I trapped by this problem for 2 days. please help.

My Mac RStudio worked well several month ago. From yestday I found I can't install packages by`install.packages()`, or download files in R. I tried a Macbook under same wifi and it worked fine. So I think it's my Mac setting problem. Trying to solve the problem, I uploaded my Mac to the latest version 12.0.1

In RStudio, I tried:

```
> library("curl")
Using libcurl 7.64.1 with LibreSSL/2.8.3
> curl::has_internet()
[1] TRUE
```

Seems the RStudio is linked to the internet. Then I tried download file and install packages:

```
> download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv", destfile="Desktop/temp.csv")
 URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv' を試しています 
 download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv",  でエラー: 
   URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv' を開けません 
 追加情報:  警告メッセージ: 
 download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv",  で: 
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>
> install.packages("ggplot2")
 警告:  unable to access index for repository https://cran.asia/src/contrib:
   URL 'https://cran.asia/src/contrib/PACKAGES' を開けません 
 警告:  unable to access index for repository https://cran.asia/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1:
   URL 'https://cran.asia/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES' を開けません 
 警告メッセージ: 
package ‘ggplot2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I tried almost same thing in Python3, neither downloading nor online installing package worked. But `scp`, `ping`, `wget` works well in command line. I can use browser, firewall, facetime, iMessage.... but the internet of r and python3 is blocked. Current conclusion: Internet is fine. some setting blocks all the app to access the internet. What should I do?

Comment: Are you connected to a proxy server? If so, you need to configure the package managers to accommodate for it

Comment: So can you open the file https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv in your browser? Is your access to just that server blocked?

Comment: @MrFlick I can access cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv on web browser, but can't download it in R.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I forgot to say that my Rstudio works well several month ago. I got the problem from yesterday.

Comment: text `package ‘ggplot2’ is not available for this version of R`  can suggest that problem is NOT internet but maybe you installed the newest version of R/Python and old modules are not ready for new version of R/Python. It is common problem if you install the newest Python 3.9 because some modules need to be recompiled to work with new  Python 3.9 (but authors may need time for this) and it is better to use older `Python 3.8`

Comment: if you use `fiirewall` then first you could turn off it and check if code works - this way you will know if `firewall` makes problem. I don't use Mac but maybe it has some system to gives access to internet only for trusted applications. On other system it could be used `firewall` for this and as default it may block all new programs and you may need manually set that new program can use internet. At least this way worked firewall `ZoneAlarm` on Windows - it blocked all unknow programs and it needed to set manually that new program may access internet.

Comment: @furas I considered that too. I turned of firewall and nothing change. Not work.

Comment: I don't use Mac so I don't know if it doesn't have other method to set privileges for access internet.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It's proxy configation. I copied the wifi proxy setting from my Macbook. Now the `pip3`, `requests.get()`, `install.packages()`, `download.file()` are working fine.

Details: on iMac, go to Systems Preferences -> Network -> Wi-fi -> Advanced... -> Proxies. **Check** Auto Proxy Discovery, Auto matics Proxy Configuration(of course you need to know proxy pac file). **Uncheck** Web Proxy(HTTP) and Secure Web Proxy(HTTPS)

Simultaneously,my iMac pluged to ethernet, and turn on the wifi. The ethernet will cover wifi and the proxy settings are separately. **Check which internet do you are really using.**